# Make output files from different input files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have multiple files with table like this:

```
16,15363,623

46,1001,209

79,74241,372

91,68063,105

57,56049,86
```

I would like to make one output file for each of this files, that shows
column average, sum, max and minimum.for ex.(output.txt)--max of the first column is : 91. Is it possible to make it with panda. And how  i use glob module here.

Comment: you can use the `glob.glob()` function to iterate through the files in a folder, also could you please post the desired dataframe for the output file?

Comment: Edvin, Welcome to SO site, would be able to provide the minimal code if you tried anything by now and what will be your desired outcome? However, its always advisable  to put some code details as bare minimum to reproduce in order to get healthy results!

Comment: @  Edvin,  see if the provided answers helping ,  if yes then accept the anwer.

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate through the files in a folder by using the below code

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
os.chdir(r'C:folder_path\')
File_list = glob.glob('*.txt')
for file in FileList:
    df = pd.read_csv(file,sep=",") #or any other seperator, check docs
    df1 = Do Some calculations and save as df1
    df1.to_csv(file[:-4]+'_output.txt',sep=",",index=False)
```

For getting max, min, sum you can use the python functions for `df.max()` , `df.min()` and `df.sum()` and save it as you want it to look like in `df1`

Answer (score 0):

I'm just placing my answer for the sake of understanding if this is what you looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

# Read multiple files into one dataframe along with pandas `concat`
# if you have path defined like `/home/data/` then you can use `/home/data/*.csv` otherwise you directly mention the path.

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(files, sep=',') for files in glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")],ignore_index=True)  # for csv files

# df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(files, sep=',') for files in glob.glob(/home/data/*.csv")],ignore_index=True) # direct path to files
```

Or

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(files, sep=',') for files in glob.glob(/home/data/*.txt")],ignore_index=True)   # for txt files
```

Finally, you can turn on the aggregation as follows:

```
$ df.agg(["sum", "min", "max"])
```

**Alternative:**
Read multiple files into one dataframe

```
all_Files = glob.glob('/home/data/*.csv')
# all_Files = glob.glob('/home/data/*.txt')
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(files, sep=',') for files in all_Files))
df.agg(["sum", "min" , "max"])
```